# Hebrew-English Interlinear Bible

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a Hebrew-English Interlinear Bible in PDF (but not scans) or Word (or maybe Adobe InDesign) format. Is it available (do download) somewhere on the web? (Or maybe some of you have one for your own use and would like to share) :)?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Questions here need a specific Bible text to discuss.  See and on-line version for the entire Bible at https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/13-27.htm

Comment: Hi, I know biblehub.com, of course. I mean PDF / Word files.

Comment: (Lines from biblehub.com cannot be copied into Word; everything falls apart.)

Comment: I copy them into Word and other applications often.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Theword.net and www.mybible.zone

Comment: You can also have it with logos and Paratext both are free.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these options will help me, because I care about the text (the entire OT) in 3-4 lines, which will not diverge. Nevertheless, thanks for all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

HiSB

> This is the [support page for HiSB](http://albesh.net) - the Hebrew interpolated Study Bible. This page will help you setup this module for [theWord](https://theword.net/) Bible study program, and also provide some additional resources to enhance its use.
>
> HiSB is a module that works within the framework of theWord bible study software. The key to using the module is the toggle keys for activating the different features.

also pdf https://scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Hebrew_Index.htm